# Matplotlib: get colors and x/y data from a bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, bar-chart

I have a bar plot and I want to get its colors and x/y values. Here is a sample code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def main():
    x_values = [1,2,3,4,5]
    y_values_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
    y_values_2 = [2,4,6,8,10]
    f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
    ax.bar(x_values,y_values_2,color='r')
    ax.bar(x_values,y_values_1,color='b')
    #Any methods?
    plt.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Are there any methods *like* `ax.get_xvalues()`, `ax.get_yvalues()`, `ax.get_colors()`, which I can use so I could extract back from `ax` the lists `x_values`, `y_values_1`, `y_values_2` and the colors `'r'` and `'b'`?

Comment: Sooorrrrt of but they'll be brittle and inconvenient. Normally you'd keep the calculated barplot values by, e.g., `rbar = ax.bar(x_values,y_values_2,color='r')` and then working with `rbar`. Can you do that?

Comment: I prefer not. But I'll settle for whatever you got :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `ax` knows what geometric objects it's drawing, but *nothing* about it keeps track of when those geometric objects were added, and of course it doesn't know what they "mean": which patch comes from which bar-plot, etc. The coder needs to keep track of that to re-extract the right parts for further use. The way to do this is common to many Python programs: the call to `barplot` returns a `BarContainer`, which you can name at the time and use later:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def main():
    x_values = [1,2,3,4,5]
    y_values_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
    y_values_2 = [2,4,6,8,10]
    f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
    rbar = ax.bar(x_values,y_values_2,color='r')
    bbar = ax.bar(x_values,y_values_1,color='b')
    return rbar, bbar

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rbar, bbar = main()
    # do stuff with the barplot data:
    assert(rbar.patches[0].get_facecolor()==(1.0,0.,0.,1.)) 
    assert(rbar.patches[0].get_height()==2)
```

Comment: I'd still like to get an answer which does not use `rbar` and `bbar` and extracts the data straight from `ax` itself. However, this is also a helpful answer. Thanks!

Comment: @noam to get from ax, you can do something like: axis = plot.gca()
bar_container = axis.containers[0]
print(bar_container.patches[0].get_facecolor())

Comment: At least test that `axis.containers[0]` is a `bar_container` if you pull stuff straight from the axis, and check for other `bar_container`s in the list. Emit some warnings for future-coder. We write this stuff assuming the plot's construction and meaning isn't going to change, and then it does...

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation to the above answers to put it all within the call to another plotting command:

```
# plot various patch objects to ax2
ax2 = plt.subplot(1,4,2)
ax2.hist(...)
# start a new plot with same colors as i'th patch object
ax3 = plt.subplot(1,4,3)
plot(...,...,color=ax2.axes.containers[i].patches[0].get_facecolor() )
```

In other words, I seemed to need an axes attribute in between the axis handle and the containers handle in order for it to be a bit more general.